# how to configure tfs build agent to build publishing profile?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a TFS build srver with vs2010.

I'm using this build template

http://ge.tt/3KQnZuR/v/0?c

On my own machine I have created a new solution in vs2012.

I have created a `publishing profile`

How can I attach this `pubxml` to the tfs-builder agent instead of the old `web deployment project` ?

Comment: The build template linked to in this question has been removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to tell TFS to do this by passing the appropriate MSBuild parameters.

- Edit the build configuration
- Goto the process tab
- In the `MSBuild Arguments` section enter the following:

`/p:DeployOnBuild=true;PublishProfile=<NameOfPublishProfile>`

This should instruct TFS to use your publishing profile when it deploys your app.